# Password security when sending email from android

Tags: android, email

There is no problems with sending emails from android through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a) technology. But there is one thing: the security of a password. I assume that we can somehow encrypt the password inside the application to make the reverse engineering harder, but what is the best way? How to ensure the security of the mail box?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail servers [support OAuth](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview) authentication for SMTP and IMAP, so you should be able to authenticate with a token, without having the actual password: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview

If you are trying to send email as someone other than the app user, you'll have to obfuscate the password embedded in the app. Another idea is to use some sort of HTTP email gateway, where you authenticate the user using their Google account, but send mail using your own service account.